# Cyclotomic Extensions and Minimal Polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Is the following an isomorphism:

$ \mathbb {Q}(\zeta_m)/ \mathbb{Q} \cong  \mathbb{Z}[X]/ X^m -1 $

Where $ \mathbb {Q}(\zeta_m)/ \mathbb{Q}$ is a field extension created by adjoining $\zeta_m$, an m'th root of unity, to the rationals ?

How about the following:

$ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)/\mathbb{Q}  \cong \mathbb{Z}[X]/ \Phi_m(X)$ where $\Phi_m(X)$ is the m'th cyclotomic polynomial ?

Comment: Notice that $X-1$ divides $X^m-1,$ so that $X^m-1$ is not irreducible.

Comment: Then I assume that means that $X^m - 1 $ is not the minimal polynomial for $\zeta_m$ with respect to the extension? Does that mean that the first isomorphism noted above does not hold?

Comment: Neither of these isomorphisms feels right to me. What is $\mathbb Q(\zeta_m) / \mathbb Q$ ? An extension of fields? But on the right is a ring which is definitely not a field. Get rid of the bad notation and the mismatching base rings and the whole question might become a lot easier.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m) / \mathbb{Q}$ represents a extension created by adjoining $\zeta_m$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. Yes, this happens to be a Galois extension with Galois group $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)/\mathbb{Q})$, but my question does not pertain specifically to this Galois group

Comment: @darijgrinberg I think you may have answered my question, if you're saying that $\mathbb{Z}[X] / (X^m -1 )$ is not a field then the first relationship does not hold. How about the the following, does that indeed hold : $ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)/\mathbb{Q} \cong \mathbb{Z}[X]/\Phi_m(X) $ where the left hand side is a field extension ?

Comment: Still, on the left hand side you have a field extension, while on the right is a ring (still not a field!).

Comment: Possible guesses as to what the texts you are reading might have been trying to say: (1) $\mathbb Q\left(\zeta_m\right) \cong \mathbb Q\left[X\right] / \Phi_m\left(X\right)$. (2) $\mathbb Z\left[\zeta_m\right] \cong \mathbb Z\left[X\right] / \Phi_m\left(X\right)$. (3) $\mathbb Q\left(\zeta_m\right)$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $\Phi_m\left(X\right)$ over $\mathbb Q$. (4) $\mathbb Q\left(\zeta_m\right)$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $X^m-1$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: (1) follows from the fact that $\zeta_m$ generates the field extension $\mathbb Q\left(\zeta_m\right)$ and has minimal polynomial $\Phi_m$. To prove (2), just construct the obvious evaluation morphism from $\mathbb Z\left[X\right]$ to $\mathbb Z\left[\zeta_m\right]$ and finds its kernel. (3) and (4) are even easier.

Comment: Thanks I was looking for (1) in your list above, as well as the fact that $\Phi_m(X)$ is the minimal polynomial for $\zeta_m$ over the extension.

Comment: I think the literature I was reading really meant (1) in your list above from the point of mathematical exposition. But since this exposition was related to the implementation of a cryptographic scheme, the scheme itself just uses integers as a subset of the rationals, which was the source of my confusion.